# Which SMS aggregators also provide voicemail services?

Tags: sms, voicemail

I am researching companies that provide both SMS and voicemail services via an API call. I want to be able to contact users (most of whom are US-based) via both text-message and voicemail. The idea is that our web server would connect to the SMS/voicemail provider's server (e.g. using HTTP post) and then send the message to the recipient's phone. In the case of an SMS message we'd send the user a text message and for voicemail there would be a translation of the text message to a robot voice and it would then call the user's phone and recite the message.

Are there any folks out there that have worked with companies that provide both SMS and voicemail? If so, can you recommend a provider?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [BT's phone/sms services](http://web21c.bt.com/) in the past. It's a great service for sending sms as well as automating calls. I particularly like the fact that everything is open sourced, and they have wrappers for a lot of main stream languages, plus the API is quite simple.

I was introduced to it in a course I took with the BT guys, and it took me a couple of days to have something not trivial running.

Comment: Thank you for the response Ramiro, I will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the following US-based providers have both voicemail (including text-to-speech) and SMS services that are accessible via an API (web service type of model).

[West Corporation](http://www.west.com/) (based in Omaha, NE)

[Premier Global Services](http://www.premiereglobal.com/) (based in Atlanta, GA)

[Twenty First Century Communications](http://www.tfcci.com/) (based in Columbus, OH)

[Varolii Corporation](http://www.varolii.com/) (based in Seattle, WA)